# Why does the user input not append to my SQL database?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm developing a login/register form for my client. Right now I am working on the registration part of the form however I seem to have encountered an issue.

I am trying to append the user's input to a database if it does not currently exist. I'm developing this functionality using PHP version 7. However, the code does not seem to append the data to the database ***even when telling me it has done so successfully***.

Here is code:

```
<?php
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            //define variables and set values to null
            $email = $code = "";

            //set variable values to HTML input 
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $code = $_POST['code'];

            //check if email exists
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT userEmail FROM userDetails WHERE userEmail=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $prepemail);

            //set parameters and execute
            $prepemail = $email;
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "email exists";
                return false;
            } else {
                //$stmt->close(); removed as per @Akintunde-Rotimi's suggestion
                //insert email into database
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO userDetails (userEmail) VALUES (?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $newemail);

                //set parameters and execute
                $newemail = $email;
                $stmt->execute();
                echo "New records created successfully";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

The code successfully connects to the database and even tells me if the user already exists. It just ***doesn't add the user's email to the database*** and I can't seem to figure out why.

I have researched methods on how to insert the data into the database using ***prepared statements*** as I have done here. I've used [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) as a reference but still no luck.

Comment: You've closed the database connection before attempting to save

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi I have applied your suggestion to my code however still maintain the same issue. Any ideas? I have also edited the question to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't seem to have any obvious spelling errors, so have you tried to catch errors? Replace

```
$stmt->execute();
```

with

```
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

You can also check how many rows are affected, -1 meaning there was an error.

```
printf("%d Zeile eingefügt.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
```

Also, enabling more errors to be shown (at least for development)

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// ...
```